# Probability that inverse mod prime is even?

Tags: nt.number-theory

What is the probability that $a^{−1}\bmod p$ is an even number in $[0,p−1]$ where $a\in\mathbb F_p\{0\}$ is

1. even?
2. odd?

Essentially I am looking in what sense are they close to $\frac12$ as a function of $p$.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A085623](https://oeis.org/A085623) and references there, in particular Guy, "Unsolved Problems in Number Theory", F12.

Comment: Is there a standard name for such sequences and are they roughly half of $p$?

Comment: According to what Guy writes that Rusza and Schinzel proved, the probability is $1/2 + O(\ln(p)^2/\sqrt{p})$.

Comment: Where do you read that information?

Comment: [Unsolved Problems in Number Theory](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387208602)